# Что такое файл .wp-config.php.swp?

Tags: php, wordpress, vim

Подскажите зачем создается и что это за файл такой  .wp-config.php.swp ? *Использую docker где файл wp-config.php идет в образе, при попытке сделать какие-то изменения в файле через команду `vim wp-config.php` открывает просто пустой файл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Подскажите зачем создается и что это за файл такой .wp-config.php.swp
> ?

`*.swp` - это временные файлы, создаваемые vim.

> при попытке сделать какие-то изменения в файле через команду `vim wp-config.php` открывает просто пустой файл

Это говорит либо об отсутствии файла `wp-config.php` либо о недостаточности прав для его правки.